# Is there a way to have the Google Sheets QUERY function's output expand horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

When a QUERY function returns more than one result cell it displays them by printing on the next row under the cell where you've written the function. Is there any way to have it print results in the column to the right of the function instead?[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap your query in [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en)

Example:

```
=transpose(query(A1:H8,"select *",1))
```